# How do I append text to the line containing a substitution in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

My goal is to replace all named constants in a `*.bas` file with their corresponding values, then append a comment to the line with the value-constant pair for future reference.

For example, I want to change this line:

```
Print #lngFile, rst.GetString(adClipString, -1, ",", vbNullString);
```

To this:

```
Print #lngFile, rst.GetString(2, -1, ",", vbNullStrings); '2=adClipString
```

Where the ADODB constant `adClipString` is replaced with its long value `2`, and a comment is appended to the line.

The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
perl -pi -e 's/adClipString(.+\n)/2$1\x272=adClipString\n/' -- somefile.bas
```

...but I can't figure out how to exclude the `\n` from the capturing group without also overwriting every line in the file. As written, the comment is placed on a new line (which is not what I want). I'm sure the answer is right in front of me.

I'm new to perl, having only run it on the command line. I'm sure there is a better [read: working] way to approach this.

Comment: Did you try moving the newline to after the capturing group? `adClipString(.+)\n`

Comment: @Thefourthbird - yes, that was my first attempt, but every line in the file was overwritten (or perhaps I should say rewritten?), and the comment was placed after the EOL (indicated by `^M` in a `git diff`). Thank you.

Comment: @toolic - thanks for your help, but that also rewrites every line in the file (rendering a `git diff` useless), and appends the note after the EOL character (`^M`).

Comment: @toolic - yes, the file is from Windows (VBA), I'm executing the perl script from within git-for-windows. For git and vim, etc. I have settings to account for the LF/CRLF issue. Maybe this is the real problem?

Comment: @toolic - that's it! I replaced the `\n` with `\r$` and moved it outside the capturing group, and got rid of the `\n` in the text to append, and it works like a charm. (How do I give you proper credit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` doesn't match newlines, and `perl -p` processes one line at a time, so the string to replace never contains more than one line, and you don't need to match the newline character at all.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\badClipString\b(.*)/2$1\x272=adClipString/' -- somefile.bas
```

I changed `.+` to `.*` because you didn't give any indication that `adClipString` shouldn't be matched at the end of a line. I also surrounded the word to replace with `\b` so that things like `thisIsABadClipStringOtherVariable` won't get replaced.

The added complication is that you have a file with Windows line endings: CR+LF. `.` doesn't match LF (line feed, the Unix/POSIX/basically-everyone-but-Windows-nowadays newline character) but it does match CR (carriage return). So this replacement puts a CR in the middle of the line (just before the comment start), which may confuse Windows programs. One way to fix this is to exclude the CR from the “rest of line” group.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\badClipString\b([^\r\n]*)/2$1\x272=adClipString/' -- somefile.bas
```

Another way to do this transformation would be to treat the string replacement and adding a comment as separate operations. An `s` command is considered true only if it makes a replacement.

```
perl -pi -e 's/\badClipString\b/2/ and s/\r?$/\x272=adClipString$&/' -- somefile.bas
```

Or, in a less one-liner-y but more readable way:

```
perl -pi -e 'if (s/\badClipString\b/2/) { s/\r?$/\x272=adClipString$&/ }' -- somefile.bas
```

The regex `\r?$` matches at the end of a line, with an optional CR. The substitution puts additional text at the end of a line, with `$&` (which stands for the whole string matched by the regex) at the end to preserve the optional CR.

Comment: If you're using Perl 5.10 or newer, there's also [`\R`](https://perldoc.pl/5.10.1/perlrebackslash#Misc) "generic newline" -- the equivalent of `(?>\x0D\x0A)|\v)`.